# KSH : Display Wait message while processing a command

Tags: echo, ksh

I'm trying to display a message (with simple echo) like "Processing" which would go "Processing.", "Processing..", "Processing...", then go back the other way, and again, and again... until a command finish executing.
The command I'm trying to do that on is a simple git clone on a branch with 'quiet' parameter, looks like this :

```sh
git clone --quiet -b dev src_path dest_path >/dev/null
```

The idea is that, no matter the number of points after "Processing" (1, 2 or 3), it stops displaying when the process ends.
Don't know if there is a native way to do this, or if this is pretty hard to do, but I'm kind of new in KSH scripting so will not understand too complex stuff (plus i'm not english fluent)

Thanks for your answers !

---

Edit : Finally found a way to do it, maybe a little longer than what I was expecting for but since it doesn't seems to be a native way helping for this, that's pretty correct. Here's what I did (thanks to markp-fuso who helped with his keywords).

```sh
    git clone --quiet -b dev src_path dest_path >/dev/null &
    PROC_ID=$!
    NB=0
    WAY=1

    while kill -0 "$PROC_ID" >/dev/null; do
        if [ $WAY = 1 ]; then
            if [ $NB = 2 ];then
                WAY=0
            fi
            NB=$((NB+1))
        else
            if [ $NB = 2 ];then
                WAY=1
            fi
            NB=$((NB-1))
        fi
        echo -ne "Processing"
        i=1
        while [ i -lt $((NB+1)) ]; do
            echo -ne "."
            i=$((i+1))
        done
        echo -ne " \r"
        sleep 0.5
    done
    clear
    echo -ne "Process complete.\n"
```

Note that I had to add a *clear* command at the end of the *while* loop because once the *git clone* is complete, the loop returns a warning saying the process doesn't exist (anymore). So I clear right after the warning displays to let it invisible for th user. If you find a way to catch it, you're welcome ! Really surprised that it displays even with the */dev/null* statement.

Comment: try a google search on `ksh bash status bar`; that should generate quite a few links; a simple idea would be to run the `git` command in the background and then have a `while` loop run `ps` to see if the `git` command is still running, if `git` is still running then `printf` a new period, wait XX secs, and repeat, and if `git` has completed then `printf "\n"` and exit the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this strategy:

```
print -n "Processing"
while true; do
  print -n "."
  sleep 5
done
```